# network interface stops working and changes to generic

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, realtek

I found many related questions, but nothing that could solve my problem:
When using my computer (Ubuntu 18.04), at any random time I get **"activation of network connection failed"** and my wifi adapter stops working.
After doing some research, I found what's causing the problem. I just don't know why it happens.

When the adapter **is still working**, I get this information:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

*-network                 
description: Wireless interface
product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
version: 00
serial: 40:9f:38:d1:83:af
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.178.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:128 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:ef000000-ef00ffff

$ sudo lspci -v

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2950
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Memory at ef000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-b8-22-01
Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

And then **when it stops working** (it can be seconds after I turn on my computer, or hours later), I get:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network

*-generic                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: ff
       serial: 40:9f:38:d1:83:af
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:ef000000-ef00ffff

$ sudo lspci -v

02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

I had dual boot with Windows 10 before, thought that was the problem so I got rid of Windows.
I've tried reinstalling my kernel, tried to run `sudo modprobe rtwpci` but it returns empty; restarting the network manager, tried `sudo ip link set wlp2s0 up` but I only get `RTNETLINK: Operation already in process` and nothing happens.

Any ideas why it just changes randomly like this? Any suggestions or possible solutions will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live 20.04.1 DVD/USB and see if the wireless stays online. Report back.

Comment: Try unloading (`modprobe -r`) and then loading (`modprobe`) the kernel module

Comment: @MaxSilvester tried that, it gets unloaded but then it doesn't load back again

Comment: @heynnema I actually installed Ubuntu 20.04 now, network went down again, but then I updated everything and so far it's working. If it fails again, I'll try do it with live USB and come back to you. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the update!